# 21 Tuesday Fast Questions for Skipping

Tags: fasting

Hi I need to know if it is compulsory to keep continuous 21 day Tuesday fast or you can skip some tuesday while performing 21 tuesdays fasts?

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous. Which source says in the first place that a Tuesday-fast must be of 21 days. Is it oral cultural source or a scriptural source? Where does this info come from? Please mention it.  Also, the question is structured as a personal advise question, you need to structure it more properly so that people answer with facts and citations. 
You are a new member, so perhaps may be unfamiliar about questions. This link will be helpful in telling how to ask questions on stack exchange https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There are plenty of Hindu traditions, each having their own fasting guidelines or rules and some don't even have rules. So, being specific may help too.